# Android : Z-index of a "RecyclerView.ItemDecoration"

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, z-index, item-decoration

I have a RecyclerView with 2 ItemDecorations.
How can I specify the elevation (z-index) of each ItemDecoration, to set which one will be drawn on top of the other?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation for `RecyclerView.addItemDecoration()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#addItemDecoration(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ItemDecoration)):

> Item decorations are ordered. Decorations placed earlier in the list will be run/queried/drawn first for their effects on item views. Padding added to views will be nested; a padding added by an earlier decoration will mean further item decorations in the list will be asked to draw/pad within the previous decoration's given area.

So basically, if you write:

```
recycler.addItemDecoration(decoration1);
recycler.addItemDecoration(decoration2);
```

The drawing will be:

1. `decoration1.onDraw`
2. `decoration2.onDraw`
3. normal RecyclerView drawing
4. `decoration1.onDrawOver`
5. `decoration2.onDrawOver`

The result of this is that `ItemDecoration`s added later will draw on top of those added earlier. The z-index is still technically the same, but if `decoration1` drew all blue and `decoration2` drew the same thing in red, you'd see the red.

Comment: The only thing I'll add here is the (1, 2) == 3, since RecyclerView is a ViewGroup and will only draw with decorations attached (see setWillNotDraw).

Comment: Yes it should be like that, but some time decoration1 is drawn on top of decoration2. (Using onDrawOver method)

Answer (score -1):

ItemDecorations just match the Z index of the RecyclerView afaik.  This is implied by the ItemDecoration.onDraw(...) [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html#onDrawOver(android.graphics.Canvas,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.State)) Since it's providing your draw method with the RecyclerView's canvas:

> void onDraw (Canvas c, 
>                   RecyclerView parent, 
>                   RecyclerView.State state) Draw any appropriate decorations into the Canvas supplied to the RecyclerView. Any content
>   drawn by this method will be drawn before the item views are drawn,
>   and will thus appear underneath the views.

It's probably one of the reasons ItemDecoration.onDrawOver(...) is also a method.

For further clarification, on the RecyclerView, it tells you that it's based on index/insertion as to when they are drawn

```
  * Add an {@link ItemDecoration} to this RecyclerView. Item decorations can
  * affect both measurement and drawing of individual item views.
  *
  * <p>Item decorations are ordered. Decorations placed earlier in the list will
  * be run/queried/drawn first for their effects on item views. Padding added to views
  * will be nested; a padding added by an earlier decoration will mean further
  * item decorations in the list will be asked to draw/pad within the previous decoration's
  * given area.</p>
```